# When I render on cloud, there is error that cant read files of addon

Tags: rendering, add-on

When I render on cloud like Concierge or Colaboratory of google, there is error like this
(↓ These errors are on colaboratory, but other services are also same)

```
Warning: Unable to open '/gdrive/My Drive/blender/assets/models/coffee_carafe_blend_36b7b8a3-b48b-4e33-ac02-1407636a9131.blend': No such file or directory
```

```
Warning: LIB: Collection: 'Pepper Mill' missing from '/gdrive/My Drive/blender/assets/models/pepper_mill_blend_3dd521be-371e-4f3a-a0d1-38fd5be72417.blend', parent '<direct>'
```

These files are appended by addon "chocofur", "asset management".
I know the reason, it's just because there is no these files on cloud. So if I set them on cloud, maybe no problem.
But it's not only troublesome, and also makes no sense. So I wanna know how can I avoid these errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File → External Data → pack all into .blend